# How to avoid printing two consecutive System.out.prints on the same line?

Tags: java

Basically, the aim is to seperate these `System.out.print`s so that the console will first ask for the persons first name, THEN once that's been entered; proceed to ask the user to type in the persons surname. Is their a way to do so i.e a way to manipulate their execution order?

```
System.out.print("Enter Person's First Name: ");
String firstName = console.nextLine();   

System.out.print("Enter Person's Surname: ");
String  surName = console.nextLine();
```

The following below is what shows up in the console and is the result of the above:

> Enter Person's First Name:  Enter Person's Surname:

Comment: What is console and how are you initializing it?

Comment: This isn't your problem. The problem is that you need to call `System.out.flush()` to write out everything to the console (normally it buffers until you send a newline).

Comment: The main issue here is that you seem to have the misconception of thinking that system.out and system.in belong together. The fact that both are displayed in the same console window has nothing to do with Java. This is purely console specific and can be completely different from console to console. On top of that, consoles tend to buffer text before displaying it to improve performance. If explicit flushing doesnt solve your issue I would recommend to try out a different console. Or to just not bother, as it is different for every user anyways.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 1):

I get a different result in my console, the one you are intending.
If you want there to be a new line after your printed messages you can use, `System.out.println("my message goes here");`

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my question is poorly worded. I'm looking for a way so that the first ```System.out.print``` will be the only appearing one out of the two ```System.out.print``` UNTIL the user has typed in his/hers answer. I'm looking for a way to not have them show up at the same time.

Comment: I have never used Jgrasp before but using Eclipse or just a online Java compiler does that. It might just be some issue with Jgrasp.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not one of printing, it is of scanning.

(I assume 'console' to be a Scanner).

The first print completes. Then you call nextLine on the scanner, which returns everything on the 'current line' up to the end-of-line.  This could well be nothing; it depends on the state of the scanner at this point.

You're expecting .nextLine() to wait for input; its definition does not say it always will do that.  Maybe .next() is what you want?

Comment: no sorry thats not it, i just want one of the system out prints to be displayed before the other. in their current state their popping up at the same time

Answer (score 0):

This should work in jGRASP on any common OS (Windows, MacOS, Intel Linux).

On other OS, or if the Linux "wedge" failed to automatically build on Linux, then I/O may buffer as you are experiencing. It could also happen if you are running jGRASP in "pure Java" mode intentionally.

Do you get a warning message the first time you compile after starting jGRASP indicating that the "Java wedge" is being used? You can use the "Help" menu in jGRASP to send us a bug report whether or not that is the case.

For now, you can run from the command line or if you are on Windows, turn on "Build" > "Run in MSDOS Window" to automatically launch a console when you run.